# Writing a Regex Expression for Extracting from a string

Tags: r, regex, extract

I was thinking I could use `str_extract_all` or something in tidyverse, but I am not sure how to get it, because what my string returns is not correct.

This is the string:

```r
str <- "12, 47, 48 The integers numbers are also interesting: 189 2036 314 \',\' is a separator, so please extract these numbers 125,789,1450 and also these 564,90456. 7890$ per month "
```

Comment: Are you just trying to extract every single number in the quote?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract_all` to extract multiple instances of one of more digits (`\\d+`).  The output will be a `list` of length 1.  So, we extract the `list` element with `[[`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(string1, "\\d+")[[1]]
```

-output

```
[1] "12"    "47"    "48"    "189"   "2036"  "314"   "125"   "789"   "1450"  "564"   "90456" "7890"
```

Comment: how would I get it to print out where each number is on a separate roe?

Comment: @zeng you can use `cat(str_extract_all(string1, "\\d+")[[1]], "\n")`

Answer (score 1):

For a base R option, we can use `regmatches` along with `gregexpr`:

```r
regmatches(string1, gregexpr("\\d+", string1))

[1] "12"    "47"    "48"    "189"   "2036"  "314"   "125"   "789"   "1450"  "564"   "90456" "7890"
```